# What does the "@" symbol mean in Excel formula (outside a table)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have recently opened an Excel file that I received from one of my colleagues and noticed that a lot of formulas have `@` symbol at the beginning. The file was saved using an older version of excel and I'm using the latest O365 version. What does the `@` symbol mean and can I remove it?

Please note that I'm aware of the use of `@` symbol in Excel table which is for [structural referencing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e). But this doesn't look the same and these formula's are not in a Table.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Excel has recently introduced a huge feature called [Dynamic arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-in-non-dynamic-aware-excel-696e164e-306b-4282-ae9d-aa88f5502fa2). And along with that, Excel also started to make a "*substantial upgrade*" to their formula language. One such upgrade is the addition of `@` operator which is called **Implicit Intersection Operator**.

### How is it used

1. The @ symbol is already used in table references to indicate implicit intersection. Consider the following formula in a table `=[@Column1]`. Here the @ indicates that the formula should use implicit intersection to retrieve the value on the same row from [Column1].
2. With the new **Implicit Intersection Operator**, you can use this to return a value from the same row in a Dynamic Range - for example: `=@A1:A10`

---

### References

According to their [documentation for Implicit Intersection Operator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34):

> Excel's upgraded formula language is almost identical to the old language, except that it uses the @ operator to indicate where implicit intersection could occur, whereas the old language did this silently

> #### Can you remove the @?
>
> Often you can. It depends on what the part of the formula to the right of the @ returns:
>
> - If it returns a single value (the most common case), there will be no change by removing the @.
> - If it returns a range or array, removing the @ will cause it to spill
>   to the neighboring cells.
>
> If you remove an automatically added @ and later open the workbook in
> an older version of Excel, it will appear as a legacy array formula
> (wrapped with braces {}), this is done to ensure the older version
> will not trigger implicit intersection.

Like mentioned in the question, the use of `@` symbol has been available in Excel tables from very long as part of Excel Table's [Structural Referencing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e). But the "**Implicit intersection operator**" is pretty new and came along with Dynamic arrays.