# How do I allow dynamic arrays by default with xlwings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlwings

I am trying to create a script that fills in cells in an array at Cell "A"
`[2, 32, 62, 92, 122, 152, 182, 212, 242, 272, 302, 315, 328, 358, 388, 418, 448, 478, 508, 538, 568, 598, 628, 658, 688, 718, 748, 778, 808, 838, 868, 898, 928, 958, 988, 1018, 1048, 1078, 1108, 1138, 1168, 1176, 1184, 1194, 1204]`
When I try to

```
for row_number in beginning_location_array:
   cell_address = f"A{row_number}"
   sheet.range(cell_address).formula = f'{{=INDIRECT("Devices!A"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))+2)}}'
```

It automatically places @ symbols and prevents my code from running correctly. This code doesn't spill into neighboring cells, so I'm kind of confused about the whole dynamic array idea. Is there a way to bypass this without having to manually press control shift enter on every cell that this was added to? Why does this occur when I use a tool to externally add formulas to Excel but not when I manually add formulas?

I tried to wrap the formula in Curly Braces
`Physical_Interfaces.range(cell_address).formula = f'{{=INDIRECT("Devices!A"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("A2:A"&ROW()-1))+2)}}'`
This did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
[Dynamic array using xlwings causing formula to be wrapped with {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384106/dynamic-array-using-xlwings-causing-formula-to-be-wrapped-with)

You need to use .formula2 or .formula_array

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).